# Copying issues on HR account

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When I am trying to run this code

```
CREATE TABLE emp_temp AS  
(SELECT * FROM employees);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE emp_temp AS 
(SELECT * FROM employees)
Error report -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 3
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

How I can handle this problem?

Comment: I am doing this in HR schema

Comment: That sounds like it might be a data dictionary problem then, and you might need to contact Oracle Support, as the message says. Although I wonder if a broken DDL trigger could generate this, so might be worth checking if one exists. You could also try creating a simple table without the `as select` to see if that's also broken.